# A question concerning 4-cycles in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Is it true that for all $g\in S_4$ and $f \in S_4$ a 4-cycle, then $g^{-1}fg=h$ implies $h$ is also a 4 cycle. I did a few examples, and it seems to be true, but I don't know how to prove it. Also, I guess it works in $S_n$ as well.

Comment: Hint: $g^{-1}fg$ permutes $\{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ by using $g$ to relabel the numbers, then permuting the result using $f$ and then finally using $g^{-1}$ to revert to the original labelling.

Comment: Your observation is that conjugation preserves cycle structure in $S_n$. Read about this in any standard textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $f \in S_4$ is a 4-cycle and $g \in S_4$, then $g^{-1}fg$ is also a 4-cycle. More generally, if $f, g \in S_n$, then $g^{-1}fg$ has the same cycle structure as $f$, and the permutation $g^{-1}fg$ can be obtained by replacing the element $i$ in $f$ by $g(i)$.  For example, if $f=(1,2,4)(3,6)(5)$ and $g \in S_6$, then $g^{-1}fg$ is the permutation $(g(1), g(2), g(4))(g(3),g(6))(g(5))$, which has the same cycle structure as $f$.  The proof is simple: Suppose $f$ takes $i$ to $j$. For conciseness let $f(i)$ be denoted by $i^f$. Then $g^{-1}fg$ takes $g(i)$ to $g(i)^{g^{-1}fg} =i^{fg} = j^g = g(j)$.

Comment: sorry, dont you mean $g^{−1}fg$ is the permutation $(g^{-1}(1),g^{-1}(2),g^{-1}(4))(g^{-1}(3),g^{-1}(6))(g^{-1}(5))$

Comment: @Haiping Yang: it depends on whether you write functions on the left of their argument or on the right. $(g^{-1}fg)(i) = g^{-1}(f(g(i)))$ if you write them on the left (as in my hint), but $(i)g^{-1}fg = (((i)g^{-1})f)g$ if you write them on the right (possibly superscripted, as Ashwin Ganesan does).

Comment: Yes, as @RobArthan pointed out, I'm using the notation of writing the function on the right.  So I wrote $(f(g(i))$ as $i^{gf}$, which equals $(i^g)^f$, i.e. the composition $gf$ means apply $g$ first.